# Using string literal macros vs pointer variables in C

Tags: c, string, variables, macros, string-literals

I print the same error message several times in my code so i thought it would be better to use variables or define them with macros;
Which solution do you think is more practical?

a)

```
char* ERR_MEM0 = "memory initialization error"
char* ERR_MEM1 = "memory allocation error"
```

b)

```
#define ERR_MEM0 "memory initialization error"
#define ERR_MEM1 "memory allocation error"
```

Comment: For only printing, then either will do just fine. However, if you choose variables then make them `const`.

Comment: It's better to have error strings as constants.

Comment: Personally I would prefer the variables, as you should use the preprocessor only where strictly necessary. But that's just my opinion, isn't it? Voting to close as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: I also prefer variables over marcos. If you mis-use a variable, you'll get a sensible error message.  If you mis-use a #define, you could get some very strange errors which are much more difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: What about a variable denoting an array of strings? `const char *errors[] = {"error one", "error two" /* ... */ };`

Comment: Why use pointers and not `const char[]`? And why `static`? What if you want to print them from another module? What if … - got it?